# Button click inside the Iframe content is not working

Tags: ios, angularjs, iframe, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins

I'm using an iFrame inside my ionic ios App to load web-page inside the content, but when I click on the button loaded inside the iframe content moves to the top and click does not work.
Following are my HTML and CSS.

```
**HTML**
<ion-tab icon-off="InductGray" icon-on="InductBlue" on-select="inductPage()">
    <div class="wrap">
        <!-- <iframe class="IFrame_Size" ng-src="{{home_induct_url}}"></iframe> -->
        <iframe class="IFrame_Size" ng-src="{{home_induct_url}}"></iframe>
    </div>
</ion-tab>
```

**CSS**

```
.IFrame_Size{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```